# How do I save my game in Neon Chrome?

Tags: pc, neon-chrome

I recently purchased Neon Chrome, and got through several floors without dying. Is there any way to save my game and return to it later?

There's a "Disconnect" option from the menu, that seems equivalent to giving up (die and quit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory serves, you can just "exit" from the menu and the game will continue from the beginning of the level.

Comment: This is indeed the answer. There's no indication of saving, but in the middle of the game, you can press ESC > Exit, and it resumes next time you pick a Solo game. Thanks!